# How to hide product with 0 price in magento 2 checkout and cart minicart

Tags: magento2

How to hide product with 0 price in Magento 2 checkout and cart mini cart.

Comment: Is the objective hide it once it is added or to prevent it from being added to the cart at all?

Comment: you can add a condition like if price more 0 then product show